# Cannot assign "'Maria'": "Aluno.nome_mae" must be a "Aluno" instance. Quando tento acessar um campo da subclass aluno

Tags: python, django

Tenho um sistema com múltiplos usuários, decidi fazer herança do User padrão do Django, tenho dois usuários: aluno e professor, que tem várias características em comum, então criei uma classe base **User** e as subclasses **Aluno** e **Professor**.

**conta/models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionMixin):
    username = models.CharField('Usuário', max_length=30, unique=True,
        validators=[validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'),
            'O nome de usuário só pode conter letras, digitos ou os '
            'seguintes caracteres: @/./+/-/_', 'invalid')]
    )

    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail', unique=True) # blank=True?
    instituicao = models.CharField('Instituição', max_length=200)
    SEXO_CHOICE = ((0, 'Masculino'), (1, 'Feminino'))
    sexo = models.IntegerField('Sexo', choices=SEXO_CHOICE, default=0)
    imagem_perfil = models.ImageField('Imagem do perfil', upload_to='media/img/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Está ativo?', blank=True, default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('É administrador?', blank=True, default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('Data de Entrada', auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    def get_short_name(self):
        return str(self)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Usuário'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Usuários'
```

**aluno/models.py**

```
class Aluno(User):
    nome_mae = models.CharField('Nome da Mãe ', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Aluno'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Alunos'
```

**professor/models.py**

```
class Professor(User):
    endereco = models.CharField('Endereço', max_lenght=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Professor'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Professores'
```

**views.py**

```
def dashboard_aluno(request):
    user = User.objects.all()
    aluno = Aluno.objects.all()
    professor = Professor.objects.all()
    print(user)
    print(aluno)# o erro acontece nessa linha
    print(professor)
    turma_aluno = Turma.objects.filter(alunos__id__contains=request.user.id)
    disciplina_aluno = Disciplina.objects.filter(turmas__id__contains=turma_aluno[0].id)
    template_name = 'dashboard_aluno.html'
    context = {'turma_aluno': turma_aluno, 'disciplina_aluno': disciplina_aluno}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Consigo fazer login com ambos os tipos de usuários, mas quando tento acessar informações que são de apenas um dos tipos de usuários, por exemplo o campo **nome_mae** do usuário **Aluno** eu recebo o erro:

**Traceback:**

```
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/rede_social/conta/views.py" in dashboard_aluno
  18.     print(aluno)
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __repr__
  116.         data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  141.         self._fetch_all()
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  966.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  275.                     obj = model(*row_data)
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  382.                 setattr(self, field.attname, val)
File "/home/andre/andre/ifce/iniciacaocientifica/rede_social/projeto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __set__
  454.                     self.related.opts.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /conta/dashboard_aluno/
Exception Value: Cannot assign "'Maria'": "Aluno.nome_mae" must be a "Aluno" instance.
```

Sou novo no Django, portanto qualquer conselho ou dica aceitarei de bom agrado.
Estou usando a versão 1.7.7 e python 3.4

Ps.: Essa é a melhor forma de ter multiplos usuários?

Comment: Você apenas colocou o modelo, coloque também a parte do código que está gerando o erro.

Comment: Esse `UserManager` é algo do próprio Django ou foi você que criou? O que ele faz? Tem como colocar o *stack trace* inteiro do erro na pergunta, em vez de só a mensagem? Pelo visto você criou a *query set* normalmente (usando `objects.all()`) mas na hora de executá-la deu algum problema. Meu único palpite é que pode ser um problema no `Manager`. Eu não tenho experiência com versões recentes do Django (após 1.5), então não sei te dizer se é ou não correto fazer subclasses de `User` dessa forma. Por que não em vez disso criar um modelo separado com `OneToOneField` para `User`?

Comment: @mgibsonbr o 'UserManaget' é do próprio Django, basicamente isso diz qual Manager(criar user e superuser) eu irei usar, nesse caso eu uso o do próprio Django. Eu pensei em criar com o OneToOneField mas eu pensei no DRY, já que o meu projeto vai ficar bem mais complexo.

Comment: Não vejo nenhuma complexidade adicional - uma "subclasse" é simplesmente uma tabela a mais cuja chave primária é também chave estrangeira pra outra tabela... Inclusive chamar `User.objects.all()` retorna todos os usuários - incluindo alunos e professores - mas você só tem acesso aos campos da classe `User`. Ou seja, a dificuldade de usar é mais ou menos a mesma. Em tempo: não estou dizendo que fazer subclasse é ruim, só estou dizendo que *eu* não tenho experiência com versões recentes do Django pra opinar sobre essa prática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de uma semana de pesquisa, descobrir que o erro estava em criar as subclasses `Professor` e `Aluno` em apps diferentes. Resolvi o problema criando as subclasses no mesmo arquivo da classe base `User`:

conta/models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionMixin):
    username = models.CharField('Usuário', max_length=30, unique=True,
        validators=[validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'),
            'O nome de usuário só pode conter letras, digitos ou os '
            'seguintes caracteres: @/./+/-/_', 'invalid')]
    )

    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail', unique=True) # blank=True?
    instituicao = models.CharField('Instituição', max_length=200)
    SEXO_CHOICE = ((0, 'Masculino'), (1, 'Feminino'))
    sexo = models.IntegerField('Sexo', choices=SEXO_CHOICE, default=0)
    imagem_perfil = models.ImageField('Imagem do perfil', upload_to='media/img/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Está ativo?', blank=True, default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('É administrador?', blank=True, default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('Data de Entrada', auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    def get_short_name(self):
        return str(self)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.nome

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Usuário'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Usuários'

class Aluno(User):
    nome_mae = models.CharField('Nome da Mãe ', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Aluno'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Alunos'

class Professor(User):
    endereco = models.CharField('Endereço', max_lenght=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Professor'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Professores'
```